# tkinter.Listbox scrolbar yview

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, python-3.5

I again encounter some problems in writing Python and would like to seek my help. I continue to build my Listbox widget but cannot setup a scrollbar. I can put the Scrollbar in the right position, however, the up and down just don't work out and pop up an error saying "Object() takes no parameter". Could anyone advise how to fix it? I attached the code below for reference.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def test():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    lst = ['1', '2', '  3', '4', '5', '  6', '7', '8', '  9', '10']
    a = MovListbox(root, lst)
    a.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tkinter.N)
    root.mainloop()

class MovListbox(tkinter.Listbox):

    def __init__(self, master=None, inputlist=None):
        super(MovListbox, self).__init__(master=master)

        # Populate the news category onto the listbox
        for item in inputlist:
            self.insert(tkinter.END, item)

        #set scrollbar
        s = tkinter.Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL, command=tkinter.YView)
        self.configure(yscrollcommand=s.set)
        s.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.S)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: I think that should be `command=self.yview`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. I tried that, but it pop out an error saying "MoveListbox object has no attribute YView"

Comment: `YView` != `yview`...

Comment: Oh, you are right! cool. Didn't realize the cap matters here. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you don't need both `import tkinter` and `from tkinter import *`

- Using `import` means you need `tkinter.'function'` to call a function
  from tkinter
- Using `from` means you can call the function as if it were in your
  program without the `tkinter.` at the start
- Using `*` means taking all functions from tkinter

Also I have fixed the code based on Rawig's answer

```
import tkinter

def test():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    lst = ['1', '2', '  3', '4', '5', '  6', '7', '8', '  9', '10']
    a = MovListbox(root, lst)
    a.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tkinter.N)
    root.mainloop()

class MovListbox(tkinter.Listbox):

    def __init__(self, master=None, inputlist=None):
        super(MovListbox, self).__init__(master=master)

        # Populate the news category onto the listbox
        for item in inputlist:
            self.insert(tkinter.END, item)

        #set scrollbar
        s = tkinter.Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.yview)
        self.configure(yscrollcommand=s.set)
        s.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.S)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```