# Python. Graphics.

Tags: python, graphics, package

I want to know about the option of the values for the "yview" command of GraphWin and a complete documentation of this package.
I'm using Python 3.6.4 version.

Thanks and regards
   Gonzalo

Comment: Could you explain more of you problem in the title?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html) for GraphWin and [tkinter.Listbox scrolbar yview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084403/tkinter-listbox-scrolbar-yview)